# How is "binomial" defined in Algebraic Geometry?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials, terminology, ideals

I am learning ideal arithmetics and I was flabbergasted that $\langle x\rangle$ is binomial ideal, as observed with Macaulay2 [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1738055/binomial-ideals-that-are-not-toric-i-e-binomial-and-not-prime). $x$ is clearly not a polynomial with two terms. Then I read [this paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/0803.3846v1.pdf):

> A binomial is a polynomial with at most two terms; a binomial ideal is an ideal generated by binomials.

So in the context of Algebraic geometry, how can I differentiate the two different meanings about binomial? When does *"binomial"* mean *two* and when does *"binomial"* mean *at most two*? Why is such difference made?

Comment: I'm not sure this is the answer since I have not seen this terminology before, but $\langle x\rangle = \langle x+x^2,x-x^2\rangle$ so it satisfies the definition.

Comment: @CaptainLama good point, still it does not explain *"A binomial is a polynomial with at most two terms"*. I would call $x$ monomial, not binomial. Yet now I understand the *"at most"* for *binomial ideal*, thank you.

Comment: What do you mean it does not explain ? $x+x^2$ and $x-x^2$ are binomials according to this definition, so $\langle x+x^2,x-x^2\rangle$ is generated by binomials. It's like saying that $\langle x, x+y^2\rangle$ is not a homogeneous ideal because $x+y^z$ is not homogeneous : this ideal is also $\langle x,y^2\rangle$ so it is homogeneous. You just have to find the right generators.

Comment: @CaptainLama I understood the sentence structure with ";" to mean redefining the term *"binomial polynomial"* (in different context meaning exactly *"two terms"*) but now after your second comment I think it to refer only in this specific context of ideals, not generally. So a reader needs to be avid to differentiate whether the context is polynomials in ideal or not. Have to still think on it.

Comment: Yes, I think basically there are two (related) notions here : binomial polynomials, and binomial ideals. And the example of $\langle x\rangle$ shows that a principal ideal $\langle P\rangle$ can be a binomial ideal even when $P$ is not a binomial polynomial (which is different from homogeneous ideals, where $\langle P\rangle$ is homogeneous iff $P$ is a homogenous polynomial).

Comment: Ah, yes this clearly seems like a bug, you should do a bug report.